# Why isn't the graph of $\ln(\tan(x^2))$ same as that of $2\ln(\tan(x))$, when they should be according to the power rule?

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms, graphing-functions

Recently, I was trying to graph the function $\ln(\tan(x^2))$ without derivatives or any calculator whatsoever. To get the answer, I used the graphing software Desmos, and was playing around when I saw that the graphs of $\ln(\tan(x^2))$ and $2\ln(\tan(x))$ are not the same. This goes against what I learned in high school, of the power rule property of $\ln$ and $\log$. Maybe it's a stupid question, I feel it is, but I can't see why and it is gnawing at me. Please explain. This is my first post, sorry if it's not properly formatted.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\tan(x^2) \neq (\tan x)^2$, and so
$$\ln((\tan x)^2) =2\ln(\tan x)$$ but
$$\ln(\tan (x^2)) \neq 2\ln(\tan x)$$

**Edit**: As noted in the other answer, you have to check the domain. Here's what I got when I tried Desmos: (they overlap when $x\in (0,\pi/2)$ mod $\pi$)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding! I entered that into Desmos and once again, the graphs did not turn out the same.

Comment: @cgug123 What did you plug in Desmos? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+ln(tan(x)%5E2)+and+2ln(tan(x))+and+ln(tan(x%5E2))

Comment: @cgug123 you have to be careful with the domain as well.

Comment: I put 2ln(tanx) and ln((tanx)^2). Sorry I don't know how to format it properly on a computer.

Comment: The wolframalpha link I gave in the above comment show you the three curves, where two of them overlap.

Comment: Thank you! So if the two are equal, why doesn't Desmos show that? I don't believe i inputted the functions incorrectly

Comment: @cgug123 Please check the update I made. And thanks for letting me know about Desmos!

Answer (score 0):

It's because the identity $\log x^n = n \log x$ holds only for $x > 0$.

Thus, here we must have $\tan x > 0$, or $x \in (0, \frac \pi 2)  \mod \pi$